# How to clean up Flink state at specific time?

Tags: java, apache-flink

Is there any way to clean up the state at specific time in Flink? For example, I need to renew state at 0:00 every day. Some elements come earlier, some later. But all of this should be erased at the end of day.
Does provide API some schedule mechanism to do so?
Or how to clean up whole operator state manually at the worst?

Comment: For what type of operator(s) do you want to clear the state?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Would it be enough to restart the job (thereby dropping all the state) every day at 00:00?

Comment: Hi David! Thank you for your answers. The problem is I have to keep some data in state that defined in (co)process operator. This data expire every 24h. I heard about TTL config for state description but I didn't found any related parameters for my problem. Hope I was clear.

Comment: There is another case: let's suppose we want to catch some event twice within 24 hours, for example, user log in. At first user is logging in at 14:00 then he's logging in at 21:00. That's the trigger. But if we just restart the job every day at 18:00 all our state is dropping and we will not catch that trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink provides two mechanisms that can be used to clear state. One is to rely on the [state time-to-live](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/state/#state-time-to-live-ttl) mechanism, and the other is to use timers with a keyed(co)process function.

Perhaps the following would meet your needs:

- set a processing-time timer every time state is created
- clear the state when the timer fires

The problem with this idea is that you'll have a timer storm if all of the timers fire at the same time (e.g., midnight). This could cause operational headaches, such as checkpoint timeouts. It might be better to stagger the state expiry somewhat, by adding some per-key jitter to the timers.

Another solution would be to take a savepoint, and run a state-cleanup job that uses the [state processor api](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/libs/state_processor_api/) to selectively drop state from the savepoint, and then restart the primary job from the modified savepoint.